# How to baseline existing migrations in knex?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

We have started using `knex-migrations` around six months back. Till then we used to run the schema changes on `staging` and `production` environment manually before each deploys.

Now we need to setup the development database on local machine of every developer. For that we are thinking to use `knex-migrations` itself. A developer will simply run the `knex migrate:latest` and the whole schema of our existing db will be up and running in local system. Then we will use seed data to populate it for testing.

The issue is that we have migrations for the schema changes for last 6 months. But not for the schema before that. I can take a dump and use it as a starting point. But I can't find any proper way for using this dump in existing migration state. As the existing `staging` and `production` databases will have the table with already run migrations.

And this particular process, which I am calling baselining, needs to happen regularly. But again, how do I handle the existing migrations state in a non hacky way.

So the larger question is, how can one do the baselining of `knex migrations`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is not an ideal situation, but the way I would approach this issue is to create a directory where all of your last 6 months migrations live say migrations/old. At that point, I would then take a dump of your current database and create a folder say migrations/sync that is just a construction of the current state of your database in the knex.js API language. At that point any future migration files should go in another folder say migrations/new. At this point, you can do an environment configuration where migrations for staging and prod use an array of directories ['migrations/old', 'migrations/new] and if the environment is dev, use ['migrations/sync', 'migrations/new']. Details of creating environment specific migrations are included here:

https://knexjs.org/guide/migrations.html#basic-configuration